# What is with the list in the special episode of Sherlock?

Tags: sherlock

In the special episode of the TV series Sherlock titled The Abominable Bride, Sherlock Holmes and his brother keep talking about a list. What is this list and what is its reference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its a list of all the drugs Sherlock has taken so that if he's in trouble Mycroft can help him.

Comment: This sounds plausible, but do you have any information to support this? He seems to have no problem with talking about the percentage of cocaine he is using, so having a secret list that says that is odd.

Comment: @Thunderforge The percentage of cocaine discussion is in his mind palace.... where he's not made an agreement with Mycroft about making a list. If Sherlock is completely incapacitated, he would be unable to discuss the drugs he's taken... which are available in a significantly wider variety than in the 1800s. The reaction that Watson has to reading the list implies that it's not a single drug but several different drugs, probably a mixture Holmes has tested over time to induce a "best state" for thinking.

Comment: Umm...i might be a lil dumb for asking this...but most of you said that the list contains the names of drugs?? So that means if he is high and in an unusual state of mind he still has the capability to write it down?? But not articulate it ?? We know that he didn't write it down before he got high cause he was high when he got on the plane but somehow in the plane he managed to write it down??

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's so that, if Sherlock is overdosing (and he can't tell), Mycroft would be able to tell the doctors what he took so that they can help him.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously none of you are users. If you have a serious habit, you need to keep track of what, when and how much you took. Not only for their agreement, but some drugs make you black out not realizing how much you took. Leading to an overdose. Sherlock mixes multi drug cocktails. In the case of an OD you have to know what they took to administer treatment.